# How to pass training progress of the data model in the webserver via WebSocket.?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, async-await

server.py

```
import asyncio
import websockets

connected_users = {}
base_endpoint = "base"

async def handle_websocket(websocket, path):
user_id = path.lstrip('/')
connected_users\[user_id\] = websocket
print(f"User {user_id} connected.")
\# print(connected_users)

    try:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            # await connected_users[user_id].send("You're connected successfully.")
            print(f"Received message from user {user_id}: {message}")
            await process_message(user_id, message)
    
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        del connected_users[user_id]
        print(f"User {user_id} disconnected.")

async def process_message(sender_id, message):
if message.startswith("Broadcast:"):
b_mgs = message\[len("Broadcast:"):\]
for user_id, user_ws in connected_users.items():
await user_ws.send(f"Broadcast message from {sender_id}: {b_mgs}")

    elif message.startswith("Specific:"):
        _, r_id, specific_msg = message.split(':', 2)
        if r_id in connected_users:
            recipient_ws = connected_users[r_id]
    
            if sender_id is not connected_users[r_id]:
                # await recipient_ws.send(f"Message for {r_id} from {sender_id}: {specific_msg}")
                await recipient_ws.send(f"{sender_id}:{specific_msg}")

async def main():
async with websockets.serve(handle_websocket, "", 8765):
await asyncio.Future()

if _name_ == "_main_":
asyncio.run(main())
```

client.py (located in the server)

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import requests
from ws_token import getWS

baseEngineAddr = "123456789"

def progress_callback(epoch):
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
\# asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
\#
\# # asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(client(), loop=loop)
\# loop.run_until_complete(client(epoch))
\# loop.close()
asyncio.create_task()
print(f'P: {epoch}')

async def count_me():
for i in range(100):
return i

async def checkToken(websocket, received_data):
global specific_user_id, r_id
if received_data:
try:
r_id, specific_msg = received_data.split(':', 2)
print(r_id, specific_msg)
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error parsing message: {e}")

        specific_user_id = r_id
    
    if specific_user_id is not None:
        message = "This message from  server."
        if specific_user_id is not None:
            if getWS.getWStoken(specific_user_id):
                conn = True
                await websocket.send(f"Specific:{specific_user_id}:{message}")
    
            else:
                await websocket.send(f"Specific:{specific_user_id}: Token not exits.")
    else:
        await websocket.send(" connected!")

async def client():
specific_user_id = None
conn = False

    print("Running websocket client....")
    url = f"ws://localhost:8765/{baseEngineAddr}"
    
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        while True:
            if specific_user_id:
                print('s data')
    
                await websocket.send(f"Specific:{specific_user_id}:")
            # if specific_user_id.lower() == 'exit':
            #     break
            received_data = await websocket.recv()
            print(received_data)
            await checkToken(websocket, received_data)

def run_websocket_client():
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    # asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(client(), loop=loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(client())
    loop.close()

if _name_ == "_main_":
asyncio.run(client())
```

#traning.py (located in the server)

```
def fit():
with tqdm(total=epochs, desc='Training Progress') as pbar:
for epoch in range(epochs):
if progress_callback:
progress_callback(epoch + 1)
pbar.update(1)

self.model = LinearRegression(\*\*self.kwargs).fit(self.X, self.y)
```

I want to transmit the progress of a trained model to the client whenever there's an update in progress, using a WebSocket. Currently, I've encountered an issue where attempting to pass the data triggers an error stating that 'await' cannot be used in a non-async function. Here's a brief overview of the process:

1. Initiate an HTTP request to generate a token.
2. Store the token in the database.
3. Receive the token as a response.
4. Connect to the server using WebSocket with the received token.
5. During user data model training, I aim to send real-time progress updates back to that specific user.

How can I resolve the 'await in non-async function' issue, and are there better approaches to achieving this goal?